# Как избавиться от лишней скрытой раскладки клавиатуры?

Tags: linux, клавиатура, fedora

Установил fedora 37, по умолчанию выбрал RU раскладку, в качестве доп - EN.
Проблема в том что, чтобы переключиться на EN - мне приходится **дважды** нажимать hotkeys. В поисках решения понял, что RU раскладка у меня как бы **скрытая** и есть еще одна RU, которую можно выбрать через стандартные настройки fedora.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данном скрине - 2 языка, а фактически - их 3.
Да, я могу удалить эту русскую в настройка, НО в таком случае в status bar не будет отображаться виджет активного языка - мне он нужен.

Как решить данную проблему?

P.S:
команда `localectl` возвращает:

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: ru
      X11 Layout: us,ru
     X11 Variant: ,
     X11 Options: grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

команда `localectl list-locales` возвращает:

```
C.UTF-8
aa_DJ.UTF-8
aa_ER.UTF-8
aa_ER.UTF-8@saaho
...
и так далее...
```

**После удаления RU раскладки** через настройки следующие результаты:
команда `localectl` возвращает:

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: ru
      X11 Layout: us,ru
     X11 Variant: ,
     X11 Options: grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

команда `localectl list-locales` возвращает:

```
C.UTF-8
aa_DJ.UTF-8
aa_ER.UTF-8
aa_ER.UTF-8@saaho
...
и так далее...
```

Comment: а что показывают команды `localectl` и `localectl list-locales` ?

Comment: добавил описание. В данные момент установлено en_US, потому что пробовал копаться в файле locale.conf

Comment: после удаления раскладки такие же результаты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта проблема возникает, когда при установке выбирается ошибочная локаль. После добавления еще двух раскладок получается 3: одна системная + 2 добавленные, - отсюда распространенная история с "залипаниями переключений". В 37 версии федоры решается модификацией /etc/locale.conf

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Вместо en_US.UTF-8 поставьте нужную вам локаль
После удалите все раскладки и добавьте необходимые дополнительные. Имейте ввиду, что раскладка != локали

Answer (score 0):

Не то чтобы это оказалось "решением", однако я попробовал переустановить систему и в этот раз выбрать за локаль(язык системы, основную раскладку) английский язык.

Проблема решилась таким образом. Лишняя скрытая раскладка пропала.